# Подсчёт времени, проведённого в приложении

Tags: java, android-sdk, android

**Дано:**

Приложение с двумя активити.

**Задача:**

Выполнение определённого действия каждые **n** минут, проведённых в приложении.

**Предполагаемое решение:**

Считать, аки **YandexMetrica**, промежуток меж **onResume()** и **onPause()** в каждой **Activity**. Т.е. писать в переменную текущее время в o**nResume()**, вычитать его из времени в **onPause()** и добавлять разницу в **long** переменную в **SharedPreference**. По достижении порогового значения выполнять действие и обнулять.

**Возможные проблемы:**

Как я понимаю, в случае падения приложения по **Exception** метод **onPause()** вызван не будет, последний промежуток не добавится.

**Вопрос:**

Как обойти проблему описанную выше? Есть ли иные подходы к решению проблемы?

**P.S.**

Сделать приложение без ошибок не предлагать)

**Решение:**

По подсказке @anber,

вместо onPause() в момент краха можно пользоваться обработчиком необработанных ошибок, зарегистрированном в onCreate():

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler()
{
    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldHandler=Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
    {
        Log.e(LOG, "Ошибка поймана");
        //здесь делаем то, что хотели сделать в onPause, но не успели, т.к. упали. 

        //Если используем какую-либо либу, обрабатывающую ошибки
        //ACRA, например, то надо вызвать дальнейшую обработку ошибки 
        //дефолтным обработчиком

        //Также это надо вызвать чтобы падение по ошибке со стандартным диалогом не завершилось ANR вместо него.
        if(oldHandler!=null)
        {
            oldHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: вынести в сервис, он останется , если приложение упадет

Comment: Согласно моим тестам, сервисы также помирают вместе со всем остальным и сразу пересоздаются. Но onDestroy() у них не вызывается.

Comment: сделать сервис фореграунд, не упадет, если нет ошибок, и сделать его минимальным )

Comment: @aratj, если имеется в виду Service.startForeground(notification, id);, то у меня и такой падал при падении приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае падения приложения по Exception можно вешать `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();` в начале `onCreate()`

Comment: А такой подход не вызовет конфликт с либой ACRA, коя ловит ошибки? Наверняка она примерно так их и ловит...

Comment: Таки конфликт с Acra вызывает, но это можно легко обойти, передав обработку ошибки (после её поимки) дефолтному обработчику. Подробнее - в обновлении вопроса.