# После обновления устройства до android 6.0 в logcat AndroidStudio 2.1.2 перестали отображаться ошибки

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

После обновления устройства до android 6.0 в logcat AndroidStudio 2.1.2 перестали отображаться ошибки. Приложения при ошибках просто вылетают, а в logcat не пишется ничего. Никакие настройки не менял. в студии стоит полное отображение всех логов, не только ошибок.

Comment: Может у вас что-то в настройках разработчика на девайсе поломалось? Проверьте там.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я смотрю там, но не могу ничего найти близкое к нужному. Да и я не менял там ничего точно. Если только этого не сделали разработчики оболочки, которую использует Huawei Honor

Comment: Вот тут пишут, что дело может быть в пустом теге http://stackoverflow.com/a/34057426/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я не про логи, которые я сам вставляю в код, а про стандартные сообщения при запуске приложения, раньше было сообщение почему крашится приложение, например:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: PID: 12323
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo.... и т.д. а сейчас вообще тишина... Ну я так понял, это из-за конкретной прошивки телефона, потому что на всех других устройствах, которые есть под рукой - все ОК.

Comment: Какой телефон хотя бы написали... У меняна HTC Desire 530 подобная проблема. Решения пока не нашел

Comment: @Fox, единственное, что могу предложить в таком случае - хак по ручному отлову ошибок. Вот тут посмотрите: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418978/17609