# Автоматический отлов вылета приложения

Tags: java, android, исключения

Всем привет, имеется Android-приложение. В связи с расширением проекта я создал 3 ветки разработки: dev, beta и stable. В веткаx dev и beta тщательно проверяют продукт на наличие багов. В случае вылета приложение должно каким-то образом не аварийно завершаться, а вызываться активность в которой будет описан текст ошибки и собранная информация об устройстве. Тестировщики должны будут сделать скриншоты.

Вообщем, собрать информацию то легко, а вот как текст ошибки достать? Как это можно реализовать? Спасибо!)

Comment: Какой язык приложения?

Comment: @Andrio Skur, Java ;D

Comment: Есть библиотека для сбора отчётов о вылетах ACRA. Она собирает стэктрейсы, последние записи LogCat'a и многое другое. С помощью нее, если не ошибаюсь, можно сделать чтобы при краше приложение "не вылетало". Но нужен сервер для хранения отчётов

Comment: @Никита Васильченко, в том и дело, что нет сервера. Хочется именно вывод на экран. Сейчас попробую что-нибудь найти

Comment: У acra открытый исходный код, можно залезть в исходники и настроить вывод информации

Comment: @Flippy, я тут посмотрел. ACRA собирает информацию и ее можно вывести где-нибудь. Например с помощью диалога. Так что попробуйте. К сожалению времени нет привести пример, но я дал вам наводку

Comment: Расставил везде `try/catch`....

Comment: @Flippy, вот тут посмотрите как отловить ошибку любую программно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418978/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, но так нельзя запустить активность

Comment: @Flippy, я сам, конечно, не пробовал, но мне кажется, что не должно быть никаких препятствий...

Comment: @Flippy, не нашел способа с Вами связаться, поэтому пишу тут. Не могли бы Вы заглянуть в этот вопрос, вроде бы Ваша тематика  — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705886/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-android-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be-android-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю Вам поможет [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra). Отлавливает Exception, Собирает неконфиденциальную информацию о телефоне и отправляет Вам на Email. Меня вполне устроило! Тут каждый пользователь станет тестировщиком...

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно использовать [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) и в нем обрабатывать исключения.

А вообще, для сборки крашей советую использовать [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/).

PS. ACRA, вроде бы, уже несколько устарела. В нынешних версиях, для получения отчетов по крашам, они советую использовать их бэкэнд, который еще нужно где-то задеплоить. Неудобно, в общем.

Comment: Crashlytics самое то, для сбора крашей, когда нет своего сервера.

Comment: Нельзя в `UncaughtExceptionHandler` запускать активность. Использовать библиотеки пока не хочется