# Декомпиляция и обновление Android-приложения до Android M

Tags: java, android, декомпиляция

Добрый день! Имеется старый проект [QEMU for Android](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=201368), который не обновлялся с 2010 года (то есть почти 8 лет). Соответственно, проект не имеет ни Runtime Permissions, ни сертификата второго уровня. Требуется заставить работать это приложение на Android Marshmallow, для начала неплохо было бы внедрить хотя бы Runtime Permissions.

---

В первую очередь я попробовал декомпилировать проект через Virtuos Ten Studio, чтобы узнать версию используемой `Activity` (именно эта программа, так как она смогла разобрать и собрать этот проект, после маленькой редакции smali-кода). На выходе получил это в методе `onCreate` в первой активности, которая стартует (код немного обрезан, так как целиком не влез):

```
   .method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    .locals 11
    .param p1, "savedInstanceState"    # Landroid/os/Bundle;

    .prologue
    const/4 v8, 0x1

    const/4 v9, 0x0

    const-string v10, "Ok"

    const-string v7, "Error"

    .line 178
    const/4 v4, 0x0

    .line 179
    .local v4, "vers":I
    invoke-super {p0, p1}, Landroid/app/Activity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V

    .line 180
    invoke-static {v8}, Ljava/lang/Boolean;->valueOf(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 192
    .local v0, "Ok":Ljava/lang/Boolean;
    :try_start_0
    invoke-static {}, LlibSDL/jni/libSDLproxy;->libSDLcheckloaded()I
    :try_end_0
    .catch Ljava/lang/Throwable; {:try_start_0 .. :try_end_0} :catch_0

    move-result v4

    .line 202
    :goto_0
    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/Boolean;->booleanValue()Z

    invoke-virtual {v5}, Ljava/lang/Boolean;->booleanValue()Z

    move-result v5

    if-nez v5, :cond_2

    .line 224
    iget-object v5, p0, LlibSDL/jni/libSDL;->sManager:Landroid/hardware/SensorManager;

    invoke-virtual {v5, v8}, Landroid/hardware/SensorManager;->getSensorList(I)Ljava/util/List;

    move-result-object v3

    .line 225
    .local v3, "liste":Ljava/util/List;, "Ljava/util/List<Landroid/hardware/Sensor;>;"
    const/4 v1, 0x0

    .local v1, "a":I
    :goto_2
    invoke-interface {v3}, Ljava/util/List;->size()I

    move-result v5

    if-lt v1, v5, :cond_3

    .line 230
    .end local v1    # "a":I
    .end local v3    # "liste":Ljava/util/List;, "Ljava/util/List<Landroid/hardware/Sensor;>;"
    :cond_2
    invoke-virtual {p0, v9}, LlibSDL/jni/libSDL;->setDefaultKeyMode(I)V

    .line 231
    sget v5, LlibSDL/jni/libSDLconfig;->CONF_DEFAULT_ORIENTATION:I

    invoke-virtual {p0, v5}, LlibSDL/jni/libSDL;->setRequestedOrientation(I)V

    goto :goto_1

    .line 226
    .restart local v1    # "a":I
    .restart local v3    # "liste":Ljava/util/List;, "Ljava/util/List<Landroid/hardware/Sensor;>;"
    :cond_3
    sget-object v6, Ljava/lang/System;->out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;

    new-instance v5, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string v7, "Sensor "

    invoke-direct {v5, v7}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    invoke-virtual {v5, v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v5

    const-string v7, ": "

    invoke-virtual {v5, v7}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v7

    invoke-interface {v3, v1}, Ljava/util/List;->get(I)Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v5

    check-cast v5, Landroid/hardware/Sensor;

    invoke-virtual {v5}, Landroid/hardware/Sensor;->getName()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v5

    invoke-virtual {v7, v5}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v5

    invoke-virtual {v5}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v5

    invoke-virtual {v6, v5}, Ljava/io/PrintStream;->println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 227
    iget-object v6, p0, LlibSDL/jni/libSDL;->sManager:Landroid/hardware/SensorManager;

    iget-object v7, p0, LlibSDL/jni/libSDL;->sensorEventListener:Landroid/hardware/SensorEventListener;

    invoke-interface {v3, v9}, Ljava/util/List;->get(I)Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v5

    check-cast v5, Landroid/hardware/Sensor;

    const/4 v8, 0x3

    invoke-virtual {v6, v7, v5, v8}, Landroid/hardware/SensorManager;->registerListener(Landroid/hardware/SensorEventListener;Landroid/hardware/Sensor;I)Z

    .line 225
    add-int/lit8 v1, v1, 0x1

    goto :goto_2
.end method
```

Много неразберихи, но я обнаружил, что сгенерировался Java-код. Уже лучше. Я взял весь код и закинул в Android Studio, добавив сверху NDK и нативную библиотеку, которая была в декомпилированном приложении. Однако, код оказался не совсем рабочим. Вот такое содержимое получилось в `onCreate`:

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        Boolean b = true;
        Label_0115:
        while (true) {
            try {
                final int libSDLcheckloaded = libSDLproxy.libSDLcheckloaded();
                if (b) {
                    if (libSDLcheckloaded == 2) {
                        break Label_0115;
                    }
                    new AlertDialog.Builder((Context) this).setTitle((CharSequence) "Error").setMessage((CharSequence) "Incompatible SDL library version").setNeutralButton((CharSequence) "Ok", (DialogInterface$OnClickListener) new DialogInterface$OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int n) {
                            libSDL.this.finish();
                        }
                    }).show();
                }
                return;
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                b = false;
                new AlertDialog.Builder((Context) this).setTitle((CharSequence) "Error").setMessage((CharSequence) "Cannot load SDL library").setNeutralButton((CharSequence) "Ok", (DialogInterface$OnClickListener) new DialogInterface$OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int n) {
                        libSDL.this.finish();
                    }
                }).show();
                final int libSDLcheckloaded = 0;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        this.requestWindowFeature(1);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1152);
        this.setContentView((View) (this.SDLview = new libSDLview((Context) this)));
        this.sManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService("sensor");
        if (!libSDLconfig.CONF_DISABLE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            final List sensorList = this.sManager.getSensorList(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < sensorList.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.println("Sensor " + i + ": " + sensorList.get(i).getName());
                this.sManager.registerListener(this.sensorEventListener, (Sensor) sensorList.get(0), 3);
            }
        }
        this.setDefaultKeyMode(0);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(libSDLconfig.CONF_DEFAULT_ORIENTATION);
    }
```

И самое важное, что я узнал — версию используемой `Activity` из строки:

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

То есть библиотека поддержки v4 или v7 не используется, а метод для запроса разрешений в реальном времени есть в классе `ContextCompat`, который содержится в библиотеке поддержки v4.

---

Так же в Java-коде был вот такой вот интересный метод, где каждый `continue` вызывает ошибку "not a loop statement" (незначительная часть кода убрана, так как целиком он просто не влезал):

```
public libSDL() {
    super();
    this.MouseMode = 1;
    this.oldSimLeft = false;
    this.oldSimRight = false;
    this.oldSimUp = false;
    this.oldSimDown = false;
    this.TrackballKillMoves = false;
    this.TP_DeltaX = 0;
    this.TP_DeltaY = 0;
    this.sensorEventListener = (SensorEventListener) new SensorEventListener() {
        public void onAccuracyChanged(final Sensor sensor, final int n) {
        }

        public void onSensorChanged(final SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            float n;
            float n2 = 0.0f;
            float n3 = 0.0f;
            Boolean oldSimRight;
            int n4;
            Boolean oldSimDown;
            Boolean oldSimUp;
            int n5;
            int n6;
            Boolean b;
            Boolean b2;
            Boolean oldSimLeft;
            int n7;
            Block_34_Outer:
            Label_0339_Outer:
            while (true) {
                Label_0332:
                while (true) {
                    Label_0302:
                    Label_0242_Outer:
                    Label_0272_Outer:
                    while (true) {
                        Label_0272:
                        while (true) {
                            Label_0242:
                            Label_0037_Outer:
                            while (true) {
                                while (true) {
                                    Label_0339:
                                    Block_8_Outer:
                                    Label_0428_Outer:
                                    while (true) {
                                        synchronized (this) {
                                            n = sensorEvent.values[0];
                                            n2 = sensorEvent.values[1];
                                            n3 = sensorEvent.values[2];
                                            if (n < 0.0f) {
                                                n = -n;
                                            }
                                            break Label_0339;
                                            while (true) {
                                                Block_29:
                                                while (true) {
                                                    Label_0080:
                                                    while (true) {
                                                        Block_6:
                                                        while (true) {
                                                            Label_0249:
                                                            {
                                                                Block_21:
                                                                {
                                                                    while (true) {
                                                                        Block_14:
                                                                        {
                                                                            Block_7:
                                                                            {
                                                                                Label_0403:
                                                                                {
                                                                                    Label_0160:
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        while (true) {
                                                                                            while (true) {
                                                                                                Label_0279:
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    Block_18_Outer:
                                                                                                    while (true) {
                                                                                                        while (true) {
                                                                                                            Block_17:
                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                while (true) {
                                                                                                                    Block_24:
                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                        while (true) {
                                                                                                                            while (true) {
                                                                                                                                while (true) {
                                                                                                                                    Label_0309:
                                                                                                                                    while (true) {
                                                                                                                                        oldSimRight = true;
                                                                                                                                        break Label_0160;
                                                                                                                                        libSDLproxy.libSDLnotifyjoystick(-(int) (3276.0f * sensorEvent.values[0]) - libSDLconfig.CONF_JOYSTICK_Y_DELTA, -(int) (3276.0f * sensorEvent.values[1]), -1);
                                                                                                                                        break Label_0339;
                                                                                                                                        libSDLproxy.libSDLnotifykey(n4, 19);
                                                                                                                                        break Label_0309;
                                                                                                                                        oldSimDown = true;
                                                                                                                                        break Label_0403;
                                                                                                                                        while (true) {
                                                                                                                                            oldSimUp = true;
                                                                                                                                            break Label_0210;
                                                                                                                                            libSDLproxy.libSDLnotifykey(n5, 20);
                                                                                                                                            break Label_0339;
                                                                                                                                            break Block_17;
                                                                                                                                            break Block_21;
                                                                                                                                            n6 = 1;
                                                                                                                                            break Label_0242;
                                                                                                                                            continue Label_0210_Outer;
                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                        n5 = 1;

                                            n2 = -n2;
                                        }
                                        if (n3 < 0.0f) {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    Label_0582:
                                    {
                                        n6 = 0;
                                    }
                                    continue Label_0242;
                                }
                                Label_0588:
                                {
                                    n7 = 0;
                                }
                                continue Label_0272;
                            }
                            Label_0594:
                            {
                                n4 = 0;
                            }
                            continue Label_0302;
                        }
                        Label_0600:
                        {
                            n5 = 0;
                        }
                        continue Label_0332;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ;
    }
```

И еще несколько `native` методов, которые тоже отмечались ошибкой:

```
public static native int libSDLcheckloaded();

public static native void libSDLcleanup();

public static native int libSDLisportrait();

public static native int libSDLmain(final String p0, final String p1);

public static native void libSDLnotifyjoystick(final int p0, final int p1, final int p2);

public static native void libSDLnotifykey(final int p0, final int p1);

public static native void libSDLnotifytouch(final int p0, final int p1, final int p2, final int p3);

public static native void libSDLnotifytrackpad(final int p0, final int p1, final int p2, final int p3);

public static native void libSDLpause();

public static native void libSDLresume();

public static native int libSDLupdatebuffer(final Buffer p0, final int p1, final int p2);
```

---

**Вопрос:** реально ли обновить этот проект для работы на Android M (а потом и O), не затрачивая на это месяцы? И, если да — как именно внедрять Runtime Permissions с остальными возможностями новых версий Android'a?

---

**UPD_0:** после декомпиляции на сайте и танцев с бубном, вышло добиться отсутствия ошибок в Java-коде. Однако, что-то пошло не так с JNI. Выскочила такая ошибка во время сборки:

```
External Native Build Issues
Build command failed.
Error while executing process D:\Development\Android_SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HD:\Development\QemuReincarnation\app -BD:\Development\QemuReincarnation\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=D:\Development\Android_SDK\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\Development\QemuReincarnation\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\Development\Android_SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\Development\Android_SDK\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-9 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=}
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Development/Android_SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Development/Android_SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Development/Android_SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Development/Android_SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:
    src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: native-lib
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Development/QemuReincarnation/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi
Build command failed.
Error while executing process D:\Development\Android_SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HD:\Development\QemuReincarnation\app -BD:\Development\QemuReincarnation\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=D:\Development\Android_SDK\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\Development\QemuReincarnation\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\Development\Android_SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\Development\Android_SDK\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-9 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=}
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Development/Android_SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Development/Android_SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Development/Android_SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Development/Android_SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:
    src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: native-lib
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Development/QemuReincarnation/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi
```

Для запуска старого проекта был создан новый проект в Android Studio. API был понижен до 4-го, Java и XML код старого проекта был скопирован в новый.

Comment: При декомпиляции Java код невалиден почти в 100% случаев. Правится только smali

Comment: С тех пор изменения произошли не только в java-api, но и в нативе. Так что есть вероятность что правкой только java-обёртки тут не обойтись.

Comment: Попробуйте декомпилировать на http://javadecompilers.com/apk

Comment: @Flippy, уже лучше. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Не может найти native-lib... Вы закинули его?

Comment: @Flippy, да. Если имеет значение, название `libnativeapp.so`, находится по пути `\app\src\main\jniLibs\libnativeapp.so`

Comment: `Cannot find source file: src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp`

Comment: @Flippy, а... Не туда смотрел. Как я понял, нативные С++шные файлы декомпилятор не смог достать?

Comment: Ой я не шарю) я просто показал куда грести )