# Обработка ошибок в Android

Tags: android, исключения

Я хочу все исключения, которые могут произойти в приложении во время работы пользователя, отсылать в Andoid Developer Console. Допустим, отсылка информации об исключении происходит с помощью метода `sendFeedback()`. И вот тут возникает вопрос: где нужно расположить этот метод  `sendFeedback()`, с учётом того, что этот метод будет использоваться во всём приложении? И как его использовать? У меня есть два предположения:

1. в классе `Application` (и далее в каждом `catch`-e каждого блока `try-catch` вызывать этот метод)
2. в классе, реализующем интерфейс
   `java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` (и далее в каждом
   активити вызывать `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)`)

Насколько это правильно? Или оба варианта плохи, и лучше сделать как-нибудь по-другому?

Comment: Второй вариант - нормальный. Можете тут посмотреть (в конце вопроса) конкретный код для отлова ошибок: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418978/17609

Comment: если стоит вопрос реализации собственного решения, то я бы поставил на application класс (но это сам я так не пробовал)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы вам не вопспользоваться готовый решением, например https://fabric.io ? Подключается его к своему приложению, и со всех устройств начинает получать статистику о падениях. Очень удобная вещица

Comment: Да, спасибо, я знаю, что есть библиотеки для обработки ошибок, и, в частности, пользовалась акрой (ACRA). Но я хочу сделать это именно без сторонних библиотек.

Comment: @Ksenia вам не кажется, что как раз люди и начали писать библиотеки, потому что стандартный инструмент не подходит.

Comment: ну, в разработке разные случае бывают, иногда приходится повторить и добавить своего.